# IE proxy is silently turned on all the time

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy

My IE is always silently turned on by setting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable to 0x1, even after I change it to 0 with regedit, it is turned on again by IE in next launch.

I figure this out by using the utility process monitor, can anyone help me further, how to fix the issue for the undesirable behavior?

Comment: Have someone remove the virus from your computer. This is a classic symptom.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a corporate network using Active Directory?

If you are, it's likely a Group Policy that's re-activating the proxy. In which case, contact an administrator to have the policy overridden for your machine.